# I don't know why the memory error can't be corrected

Tags: c, list, data-structures, linked-list

After "3rd round" was printed, an exception occurred in p, so we added the part that initializes free(min_node) and min_node to NULL to the delete_min function. However, heap memory error exception continues to occur.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//*
typedef struct user {
    char name[100];
    int point;
} element;

typedef struct ListNode {
    element data;
    struct ListNode* link;
} ListNode;


void error(char* message) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
    exit(1);
}

ListNode* insert_first(ListNode* head, element value)
{
    ListNode* p = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); 
    p->data = value;
    p->link = head;
    head = p;
    return head;
}


ListNode* insert(ListNode* head, ListNode* pre, element value)
{
    ListNode* p = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    p->data = value;
    p->link = pre->link;
    pre->link = p;
    return head;
}


ListNode* delete_first(ListNode* head)
{
    ListNode* removed;
    if (head == NULL) return NULL;
    removed = head;
    head = removed->link;
    free(removed);
    return head;
}


ListNode* delete(ListNode* head, ListNode* pre)
{
    ListNode* removed;
    removed = pre->link;
    pre->link = removed->link;
    free(removed);
    return head;
}

void print_list(ListNode* head) 
{
    for (ListNode* p = head; p != NULL; p = p->link) {
        printf("(%s  : %d) ", p->data.name, p->data.point);
    }
    printf("NULL \n");
}


ListNode* delete_min(ListNode* head)
{
    if (head == NULL) { 
        printf("List is empty.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    ListNode* min_node = head;
    ListNode* p = head;
    ListNode* prev = NULL;

    // search minimum node
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->data.point < min_node->data.point) {
            min_node = p;
            prev = (prev == NULL) ? head : prev->link;
        }
        else {
            prev = p;
        }
        p = p->link;
    }

    // delete minimum node 
    if (min_node == head) {
        head = head->link;
        prev = NULL;
    }
    else {
        prev->link = min_node->link;
    }
    printf("OUT: %s (%d)\n\n", min_node->data.name, min_node->data.point);
    free(min_node);
    min_node = NULL; 

    return head;
}

ListNode* list_random(ListNode* head)
{
    ListNode* p = head;

    while (p != NULL) {
        p->data.point += rand() % 1000;
        p = p->link;
    }
    return head;
}


int main(void)
{
    ListNode* head = NULL;
    int i;
    int random;
    element user[5];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        memset(&user[i], 0, sizeof(element));
    }

    strcpy(user[0].name, "yeeun");
    strcpy(user[1].name, "yumin");
    strcpy(user[2].name, "sangeun");
    strcpy(user[3].name, "soeun");
    strcpy(user[4].name, "juhui");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        head = insert_first(head, user[i]);
    }
    print_list(head);

    printf("\n");

    printf("1st round\n");
    list_random(head);
    print_list(head);
    head = delete_min(head);

    printf("2nd round\n");
    list_random(head);
    print_list(head);
    head = delete_min(head);

    printf("3rd round\n");
    list_random(head);
    print_list(head);
    head = delete_min(head);

    printf("4th round\n");
    list_random(head);
    print_list(head);
    head = delete_min(head);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `delete_min` looks complicated and it has has a bug. Look at the list before and after `head = delete_min(head);` after 2nd round. Use the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: I suggest you write a function that finds the minimum node and then just call a function  `deletes_node(ListNode *head, ListNode *tobedeleted)` (to be written). Hint: a pencil and a piece of paper is most useful here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest issue you have here is `delete_min`.  Looks like the broken logic is in this loop:

```
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->data.point < min_node->data.point) {
            min_node = p;
            prev = (prev == NULL) ? head : prev->link;
        }
        else {
            prev = p;
        }
        p = p->link;
    }
```

According to `prev = p;`, `prev` represents the previous link to `p`.  But according to `prev = (prev == NULL) ? head : prev->link;`, `prev` is the previous link to `min_node` (NOTE: this logic is quite flawed as `prev->link` is `p`).  So you are using this variable to represent more than one thing.  This can be fixed by adding another variable.  Let's call that `min_node_prev`.  Now, the logic can be greatly simplified:

```
ListNode* delete_min(ListNode* head)
{
    if (head == NULL) {·
        printf("List is empty.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    ListNode* min_node = head;
    ListNode* min_node_prev = NULL;
    ListNode* p = head;
    ListNode* prev = NULL;

    // search minimum node
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->data.point < min_node->data.point) {
            min_node = p;
            min_node_prev = prev;
        }
        prev = p;
        p = p->link;
    }

    // delete minimum node·
    if (min_node == head) {
        head = head->link;
        // don't care about prev anymore
    }
    else {
        min_node_prev->link = min_node->link; // NOTE: change here
    }
    printf("OUT: %s (%d)\n\n", min_node->data.name, min_node->data.point);
    free(min_node);
    min_node = NULL;·

    return head;
}
```

There are some other unrelated issues I noticed.  Generally, don't cast the return of `malloc`.  That is a C++ thing:

```
ListNode* p = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
```

The more idiomatic way to approach this in C would be to use the variable itself:

```
ListNode* p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

Also, the `memset` really isn't necessary:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        memset(&user[i], 0, sizeof(element));
    }
```

For one, it is an array, so they are contiguous in memory.  You could get rid of the loop and just do:

```
memset(user, 0, sizeof(user));
```

...or just initialize them directly and you could get rid of the `strcpy` calls as well:

```
    element user[5] = {
        {.name = "yeeun"},
        {.name = "yumin"},
        {.name = "sangeun"},
        {.name = "soeun"},
        {.name = "juhui"},
    };
```

Since this uses "designated initializers," all other variables in the struct are implicitly set to 0.